# Using ngx-formly in Angular 10 - is there an easy way to add a toggle next to each field

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ngx-formly

In my app I added a new form using .
To each field in my form I receive from the server an indication if this field has been changed and I need to present it as a toggle near each field.

Is there an easy way to do it with ngx-formly?

Thanks!

I read carefully in the documentation but could not find a way of doing it.